# Got a virus that every once in a while opens a new tab in any browser

Tags: virus

Got a virus that every once in a while opens a new tab in any browser. It does so even while I am watching video on YouTube - it just goes ahead and opens up a new tab with some page from the internet. It is quite annoying. Is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score -1):

Try using some anti-virus software. I recomend HitmanPro, Avira, MalwareBytes or AVG. Just run a full system scan with all of these.

Download links:

- [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/antimalware/)
- [AVG](http://www.avg.com/ww-en/homepage)

Just a pro tip: After downloading something from the internet, be sure to check it with virustotal.com.

Comment: Who made this question -1, then why?

Comment: Here is some information as to why you may have gotten a down vote - [How to not be a spammer](http://superuser.com/help/promotion). You may not be spamming, but read this to better understand why your answer needs serious improvement.

Comment: I'd say that this would be a better answer if you gave *reasons* for your recommendations. Also, in the original version of this answer, you explicitly said that it wasn't a full answer. Don't worry about downvotes unless they're overwhelming: most of us have a few downvoted posts, and it does take a while to get used to how Stack Exchange sites operate.